# stopping execution of code is not working

Tags: php, html

when i click on start it should start executing the code and when i click on stop it should stop execution and print whatever it has executed.
when i run the following code it is not working
what actually i want is when i click on start it should start printing the number from 1 to 50 inbetween when i click on stop it should print the numbers still where it has executed

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="start" id="start" name="start" />
   <input type="submit" value="stop" id="stop" name="stop" />
</form>

if ( isset( $_POST['start'] ) ) {
   for ( $i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++ ) {
      echo $i."<br/>";
      if ( isset( $_POST['stop'] ) ) {
         die( print_r( $i ) );   
      }
      sleep('1');
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you have some confusion about what can and can't be done with PHP.

Comment: Use javascript to do such type of work.

Comment: What do you expect the code to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: @WesleyMurch what is happening is it is printing the numbers from 1 to 50 even after clicking on stop button

Comment: PHP prints the numbers before it even sends the markup to the client where you could press stop. This is not how PHP functions, you can't do what you're trying to do with PHP.

Comment: @markus then it cant be done in php?

Comment: I understood your expectation. It can be done easily using JS/jQuery

Answer (score 2):

A working copy for you using `jquery`

```
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" name="start" />
<input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" name="stop" />

<div id='output'></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
                type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var timeOut = null;
var i = 0;
var printStuff = function() {
    if(i>=50) return;
    i++;
    $("#output").append(i+" ");
    timeOut = setTimeout(printStuff,1000);
};

$("#start").click(function() {
    timeOut = setTimeout(printStuff,1000);
});
$("#stop").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
});
</script>
```

Comment: wow it works but not able to understand the logic

Comment: can it be done in two different pages for ex:start in one page and stop in other page

Comment: Yes it can be done using cookie/database and ajax though it will be bit more complex to manage.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody said, this should not be done by php, should better be done by javascript or any other client side language.

But if you are trying to learn php or some aspect of it by this code then you can use this code.

```
<?php 
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>

<form method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="start" id="start" name="start"/>
<input type="submit" value="stop" id="stop" name="stop" onclick="document.getElementById('trackback').value = document.getElementById('counter_port').innerHTML; return true;"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" id='trackback' name='trackback'/>
<span id='counter_port' name='counter_port'>
<?php               
   if(isset($_REQUEST['start'])){          

            echo "<br/>";
            for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++){
                echo $i."<br/>";
                if(sleep(1) != 0) {
                    echo 'sleep failed';
                    break;
                }
                flush();
                ob_flush();
            }

    } else {
        echo $_REQUEST['trackback'];
    }
?>
</span>
</form>
```

Again, this is a wrong way of doing what we did here.

Comment: Why do you check for the same thing twice?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code may be it help you

```
if ( isset( $_POST['start'] ) ) {
   for ( $i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++ ) {
      echo $i."<br/>";
      sleep('1');
   }
}
  if ( isset( $_POST['stop'] ) ) {
     exit("Code is stopped");
  }
```